# Running embedded HotRod Infinispan server

Tags: infinispan

I'm trying to deploy Infinispan cluster where each node running embedded HotRod server :

```
new HotRodServer().start(new  HotRodServerConfigurationBuilder().host("10.1.1.6").port(11322).build(),
            new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml"));
```

client :

```
remoteCache = new RemoteCacheManager().getCache("myCache");
```

client cfg:

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list=10.1.1.6:11322
```

The problem is that  remoteCache is empty although I'm sure the JPA loader defined in infinispan.xml does it's work and I see positive entities count in jconsole for myCache entry.

Am I missing something ?

Another question : how do I expose REST endpoint on HotRod server started this way ?

dependencies :

```
'org.infinispan:infinispan-server-hotrod:5.3.0.Final',
'org.infinispan:infinispan-core:5.3.0.Final',
'org.infinispan:infinispan-cachestore-jpa:5.3.0.Final',
'org.infinispan:infinispan-client-hotrod:5.3.0.Final',
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you check that the server is empty? Retrieving the keys directly, or via keySet? Via size?

Comment: And for REST, you have to start REST server.

Comment: I checked via size and explicit get. Size returned me -1, and get - null for the object I'm sure is there

Comment: I just tried to get keySet and    got org.infinispan.CacheException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Class cannot be casted to array. Looks like this is marshalling issue : I load cache with JPALoader and getting the cache with remote client. How do I make sure I use the same marshaller on both sides ?

Comment: Could you try to setup TRACE logging on org.infinispan for both server and client?

Comment: I posted a working example of an embedded HotRod server [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29732615/880772). You have a second question, that should be in another post.