# How to view and edit Infinispan cached data remotely

Tags: java, caching, jboss, wildfly-8, infinispan

I have an Infinispan cache embedded in a WildFly 8.2 server.

I added to `standalone.xml` inside `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">`:

```xml
<cache-container name="mycache" default-cache="cachedb">
    <transport lock-timeout="600000" />
    <replicated-cache name="cachedb" batching="true" mode="SYNC" />
</cache-container>
```

...and injected the cache container like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CacheManager {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/mycache")
    private CacheContainer container;
    . . . . 

}
```

I can use the cache in my applications.

However the requirement is to see/edit/delete the cached data remotely by using any of the cache monitoring APIs.

Via jconsole I can see the cache information, but not the cached data.

[image: jconsole screen]

How can I access the cache remotely?

Comment: Did you consider using [Infinispan Server](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/infinispan_server_guide/infinispan_server_guide.html) ?

Comment: NO. The requirement is to embed infinispan in wildfly server.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that's all you can do. Accessing Infinispan cache remotely only available with Infinispan Server.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, my condolences on having to choose the road less traveled.

It's possible to access an embedded Infinispan cache remotely. You need to set up a `org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodServer` in your server process, essentially reverse engineering the pre-packaged [Infinispan Server](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/infinispan_server_guide/infinispan_server_guide.html) distribution. **This approach is not documented, so proceed at your own risk**.

You need these dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-server-hotrod</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-remote-query-server</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure an example cache (`infinispan.xml`):

```xml
<infinispan>
    <cache-container default-cache="default">
        <local-cache name="dumpster">
            <compatibility />
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

The server process:

```java
// Start a cache manager as usual
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;
try (InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("infinispan.xml")) {
    cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(in);
}

// Start a server to allow remote access to the cache manager
HotRodServerConfiguration serverConfig = new HotRodServerConfigurationBuilder()
        .host("127.0.0.1").port(9999).build();
HotRodServer server = new HotRodServer();
server.start(serverConfig, cacheManager);

// Start the example cache
Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.getCache("dumpster", true);
cache.put("K", "V");
System.out.println(cache.get("K")); // V
```

The client process:

```java
Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().addServer()
        .host("127.0.0.1").port(9999).build();
RemoteCacheManager cacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(config);
RemoteCache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.getCache("dumpster");
System.out.println(cache.get("K")); // V
```